# Karate How to save each response when running scenario outline/examples in parallel

Tags: karate

Given i have something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: test
    Given request {"movie":"<title>","age":"<age>"}
    When method post
    Then status 201
    Then match response contains {"something": 52.0833} || {"something": 27.160493}
Examples:
      | title | age 
      | test  | 30 
      | test1 | 40
```

Now i'd like to verify that the given response 52.0833 and 27.160493 are present in each response body.

Given that these are run in parallel, does karate have a way of saving both requests to a variable or doing something like i tried above i.e using || operator or 'either'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions

```
Given def response = { something: 52.0833 }
Then match response contains { something : '#? _ == 52.0833 || _ == 27.160493' }
```

You should never consider saving responses to a file, always validate then and there and move on.